# Set precision dynamically using sprintf

Tags: c, printf, format-string

Using sprintf and the general syntax `"%A.B"` I can do this:

```
double a = 0.0000005l;
char myNumber[50];
sprintf(myNumber,"%.2lf",a);
```

Can I set A and B dynamically in the format string?

Comment: Yes you can, see e.g. [this `printf` (and family) reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf).

Comment: Alternatively, the format string itself could also be created with another call to sprintf.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, you can do that. You need to use an asterisk `*` as the field width and `.*` as the precision. Then, you need to supply the arguments carrying the values. Something like

```
  sprintf(myNumber,"%*.*lf",A,B,a);
```

Note: `A` and `B` need to be type `int`. From the `C11` standard, chapter §7.21.6.1, *`fprintf()`* function

> ... a field width, or precision, or both, may be indicated by an asterisk. In
>   this case, an `int` argument supplies the field width or precision. The arguments specifying field width, or precision, or both, shall appear (in that order) before the argument (if any) to be converted. A negative field width argument is taken as a `-` flag followed by a positive field width. A negative precision argument is taken as if the precision were omitted.

Answer (score 4):

Yes - You use "*" e.g.

```
sprintf(mynumber, "%.*lf", 2, a);
```

See http://linux.die.net/man/3/sprintf